# Payflow Pro hosted checkout now setting x-frame-options to sameorigin on https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com

Tags: iframe, paypal, x-frame-options

We use an iframed hosted checkout page and it is currently working fine in production.  In our dev environment, the iframe is not displaying because the page at https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com/?SECURETOKEN=...&SECURETOKENID=...&MODE=TEST has x-frame-options set to sameorigin.
Is this new behavior?  How can we use hosted checkout in the iframe?
Thanks.
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same here, so I sent a the message below to @AskPayPal (PayPal support) yesterday. No reaction so far.

Starting last friday 16 feb., the response to " https://pilot-payflowlink.paypal.com/?SECURETOKEN=9t1K1o0GlwEyhdVCAPx8ZtwzP&SECURETOKENID=48024962-3d01-4331-bf9b-2f782bb33e32&MODE=TEST …" contains X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN which prevents the paypal form to be loaded in an iframe. 
On a production account this header is not (yet) added.
Since we are using the "Layout C" for the hosted checkout pages we actually want to use an iframe.
On the configuration page the text for "Layout C" still says: "Layout C can either be framed on your site or be a stand-alone popup."
Is this a temporary problem on the pilot site or is this going to be deployed on production (and if so, when)?

Comment: Yup.  Thanks for posting that you're seeing the same issue.  I pinged @AskPayPal too.

Comment: I got this from PayPal support team: ''We have discovered that a security update to our pilot Payflow link servers have caused some traffic to encounter this error. Our team is aware of the issue and are working on correcting the issue on all pilot servers. I will update you when this fix is pushed.''